# Using a Swing Timer to hide a notification temporarily

Tags: java, swing

I'm using a Swing `Timer` to make `webNotification`, a custom `JFrame`, appear at a certain time. I want the user to have the option of clicking a "Hide" button that dismisses the notification and makes it come back after an hour. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`javax.swing.Timer`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) has an initial delay; just set it to `60 * 60 * 1000`. Your `actionPerformed()` will be called an hour after invoking `start()`.

Addendum: Here's an example of a button that hide's it's enclosing window for a specified period of time.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373493 */
public class TimerFrame extends JFrame {

    private void display() {
        this.setTitle("TimerFrame");
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.add(new TimerButton("Back in a second", 1000));
        this.add(new TimerButton("Back in a minute", 60 * 1000));
        this.add(new TimerButton("Back in an hour", 60 * 60 * 1000));
        this.pack();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    /** A button that hides it's enclosing Window for delay ms. */
    private class TimerButton extends JButton {

        private final Timer timer;

        public TimerButton(String text, int delay) {
            super(text);
            this.addActionListener(new StartListener());
            timer = new Timer(delay, new StopListener());
        }

        private class StartListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                TimerFrame.this.setVisible(false);
                timer.start();
            }
        }

        private class StopListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.stop();
                TimerFrame.this.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimerFrame().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but what in case when time delay is not within 24 hrs but within one week or more than it? Should we have to count hours till that day and set it in delay?Or is there any other way?

Comment: @bsm: [Quartz](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/quartz) is a popular choice, but I typicaly use [`at`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?at).