# Show HTML file in JEditorPane

Tags: java, html, swing, awt, jeditorpane

I am working on a Swing application in which I have to show HTML files.

I am using `JEditorPane` control for it. It is showing the content of HTML file but not in the same format as originally in the actual HTML file.

`JEditorPane` does not support the `object` element.  Rather than loading the object file its just showing `?`.

Is there any other inbuilt control in Swing to browse the HTML file rather than `JEditorPane`?

I am using the following code:

```
JEditorPane HtmlPane= new JEditorPane();
File file1= new File("path of the file");
HtmlPane.setContentType("text/html");
HtmlPane.setEditable(false);
HtmlPane.setPage(file1.toURI().toURL());
JScrollPane jsp=new JScrollPane(HtmlPane);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet for more advanced HTML rendering in core Java is to use the JavaFX based `WebView` component as described in [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm).  It supports HTML5, but I've not actually played with it, so I cannot say how well it renders HTML.

Note that Java FX is effectively an alternative to Swing, but AFAIU Java FX components can be embedded in Swing GUIs.

Comment: An example using `JFXPanel` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513).

Answer (score 2):

Support for [*HTML in Swing Components*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) is [limited](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) to [3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), predating the `<object>` tag. You might be able to use a `HyperlinkListener`, illustrated [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/HyperlinkListenerExample.htm), in conjunction with [`Desktop#browse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29). See also this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12827643/230513).

Comment: +1, but with the amount of trouble I had shoehorning an applet element into a `JEditorPane` together with what it typically does to subtly styled HTML, I feel there is really nothing that can be done to make it into a serious browser component. :(

Comment: >  Add HTML Content to JavaFX>You could begin about here: [Adding HTML Content to JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm), there Will be issues because the API has _improved_ since **2014**. Basics almost always stay-focused.  Don't they?!!

Comment: @will: An example using `JFXPanel` is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513).

Answer (score -1):

To render html content from local file, the local file's extension must be ".html". JEditor Pane will render "content.html" but will not render "content.txt".

Comment: HTML / XML is-a byte-stream, or MIME-type. No magic _file-type_ required/