# Any way to take screenshot of URL in java

Tags: java, swing, screenshot, lobo-cobra

Please suggest the way to take screenshot of URL/HTMLFile in java.
I am trying with [LOBO Browser](http://lobobrowser.org/) and able to Open URL in jframe but not able to take screenshot of content inside jframe.
Please check code sample

```
import org.lobobrowser.gui.FramePanel;

public LoboTestFrame() throws Exception {
    FramePanel framePanel = new FramePanel();

    this.getContentPane().add(framePanel);
    framePanel.navigate("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");

}
```

Not able to capture loaded content as image

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853879/swing-obtain-image-of-jframe

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Combine [`Desktop#browse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse-java.net.URI-), mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253383/230513), with [`Robot#createScreenCapture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture-java.awt.Rectangle-), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3742731/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5853992/230513).

Comment: hi thnx for your response but i cannot capture screen.I need to get image of content loaded through Lobo browser or any other good html render  api. these example not loading complex html pages properly

Comment: i dont want Jframe visibility ..just want to save the loaded url as image

Comment: `Desktop#browse()` is the easiest way to get a correctly rendered page; more on headless operation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13985919/230513).