# How to create a JMenuBar with Glossy Colors?

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I created a small Swing based application. For that I created a menu bar using `JMenuBar` class. But I want to apply glossy color for that menu bar.

In particular, I'm look at the effects seen [here](http://www.webstockbox.com/css/50-cool-css-menus-free-source-codes-tutorials): a gradient color in the fifth example and an animation in the seventh.

My Code:

```
public class MenuBar extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form MenuBar
 */
public MenuBar() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    jMenu2.setText("Edit");
    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuBar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuBar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuBar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MenuBar.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MenuBar().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: *"But,I want to apply Glossy Color Nature "* - got an example?

Comment: Is It possible to add Glossy Colors to JMenuBar.

Comment: Most likely, but what is you expected result?

Comment: Do you have an example image of what it would look like?  If so, please link to it or better still, embed it in the question.

Comment: Example for My Problem is,some of the Website Menu Bar are Designed By CSS Styles.Those are Looks like Glossy Color Nature.How can I integrate the CSS and HTML code for My JMenuBar.

Comment: http://www.webstockbox.com/css/50-cool-css-menus-free-source-codes-tutorials

Comment: See The Above link.In that link I want 5th or 7th Glossy color type menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

While your question is very broad, several points are worth mentioning:

- As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13253383/230513), support for CSS in Swing is limited; [JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javafx/info) may be an alternative.
- In Swing, the appearance of a `JMenuItem` is controlled by its UI delegate, typically derived from `BasicButtonUI`; an example of applying a gradient is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5755124/230513).

  [image]
- Alternatively, add instances of `JButton` to a [`JToolBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html), illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14599176/230513); use the [rollover](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) property to change the button's icon as desired.

  [image]
- Create animated icons using a Swing [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3484251/230513).

  [image]