# JavaFX WebView grow to fill entire area

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I'm trying to make a javafx WebView that expands to the surrounding JPanel. According to this thread: http://www.coderanch.com/t/634791/JavaFX/java/Resizing-HTMLEditor-JavaFX, there is a bug in the WebView where you need to call `GridPane.setHgrow` and `GridPane.setVgrow` on the WebView. I've peppered my code with those calls, but the WebView is still 600x800px.[image: jxframe sadness]

Note that the Scene has a blue background, so you can see that the javafx stuff does fill the entire JPanel. But the WebView does not fill the javafx Group/Scene.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main {

    private void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JButton button = new JButton("button");
        panel.add(button, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        panel.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFX(fxPanel);
            }
       });
    }

    private WebView webView;

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);

        GridPane.setHgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);

        webView = new WebView();
        GridPane.setHgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);


        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);

        GridPane.setHgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);
        GridPane.setVgrow(webView, Priority.ALWAYS);

        return scene;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Main().initAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, see also [*JavaFX: Interoperability: 3 Integrating JavaFX into Swing Applications*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach is to add the `WebView` to a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html), which "will attempt to resize each child to fill its content area." I've given the enclosing `JFXPanel` to an arbitrary [preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513) size of `640 x 480`; resize the frame to see how the `StackPane` reflows the `WebView` content based on the default `Pos.CENTER`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513 */
public class WebViewTest {

    private void initAndShowGUI() {
        // This method is invoked on the EDT thread
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel(){

            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        };
        frame.add(fxPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        });
    }

    private void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
        Scene scene = createScene();
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

    private Scene createScene() {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        WebView  webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.example.com");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        return scene;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new WebViewTest()::initAndShowGUI);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, this works, and doesn't involve subclassing Region like my solution required. I like this way better.

Comment: See also the related examples shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/44091479/230513) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32396344/230513).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think I got a solution based off http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.java.htm:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class WebViewSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing and JavaFX");
        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        final JFXPanel jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
        panel.add(jfxPanel);

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                initFx(jfxPanel);
            }
       });
    }

    private static void initFx(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 1000, 1000, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        fxPanel.setScene(scene);
    }

}

class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        // load the home page
        webEngine.load("http://www.google.com");

        //add components
        getChildren().add(browser);
    }

    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        double w = getWidth();
        double h = getHeight();
        layoutInArea(browser,0,0,w,h,0,HPos.CENTER,VPos.CENTER);
    }

}
```

I think the trick is to subclass Region, so that you can layout the WebView where you want it manually.