# How can I set a JavaFX WebView as big as the scene?

Tags: java, css, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have a JavaFX WebView which I want to have as big as the scene on start. If I could make it resize with the scene, this would be perfect.
But right now I focus just on the initial size.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    try {
        Scene scene = new Scene(createWebViewPane(), 1920, 1080);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Styles/application.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The above code creates a scene with width: 1920px, height: 1080px. `createWebViewPane()` creates a WebView on a pane.

```
private Pane createWebViewPane() {
    final Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.minWidth(1920);
    pane.minHeight(1080);
    WebView browser = new WebView();
    browser.minWidth(1920);
    browser.prefWidth(1920);
    browser.minHeight(1080);
    browser.prefHeight(1080);
    WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("index.html").toExternalForm());
    pane.getChildren().add(browser);
    return pane;
}
```

There I try to set the width / height. I also set it in the stylesheet.

```
web-view{
    -fx-font-scale: 1;  
    -fx-min-width: 1920px;   
    -fx-min-height: 1080px;   
    -fx-pref-width: 100%; 
    -fx-pref-height: 100%;
}
```

But none of these properties seem to affect the WebView. It still has it's default size. 800px in width and 600px in height.

Comment: Try a `StackPane`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31574311/230513).

Comment: Glad it helped. Rather than close this question as a duplicate, I added an answer specific to [tag:javafx]; the other answer is more about [tag:swing].

Comment: Jep, noticed it as well, but could adapt it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the `WebView` to a [`StackPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html), which "will attempt to resize each child to fill its content area." Resize the frame to see how the `StackPane` reflows the `WebView` content based on the default `Pos.CENTER`.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33824164/230513 */
public class WebViewPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.load("http://www.example.com");
        root.getChildren().add(webView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("WebView");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: An updated variation may be found [here](https://gist.github.com/trashgod/0fc8eb920ba9ee5e04b2810a9176d440).