# In WebView, perform zoom in and out function while I press + and - key

Tags: java, javafx

As I'm making JavaFX application three in three `WebView` in my application, I have to perform zoom in and out function while I press + and - key. Code is given below:

```
  StackPane root = new StackPane();

        HBox hbox = new HBox(30); // create a HBox to hold 2 vboxes        

        // create a vbox with a textarea that grows vertically
        VBox vbox = new VBox(10);  
        //Label label1 = new Label("");

        final WebView img = new WebView();
         final WebEngine Img = img.getEngine();
         final DoubleProperty zoomProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(200);
 img.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
                System.out.println("YES");
                    zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() * 1.1);
            }
            else if(e.getCode()== KeyCode.SUBTRACT||e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS ){
                System.out.println("YES");
                zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() / 1.1);
            }
        });
```

As through this code im able to listen to the key but zoom in and zoom out is not working. Please help as I have to change mouse pointer to double headed arrow then listen to arrow and + and - key for zoom in and out.

Comment: Please add a meaningful readable title to your question. Don't just copy your question to your title or vice versa. PS: There is a "shift" hey on your keyboard. Consider using it.

Comment: What happens if you update the zoom property of the WebView?

Comment: nothing happens as it has already have the functionality with mouse listener to zoom in and zoom out but i dont want it with mouse listener i want it with key listener

Comment: As it works for me, I've elaborated below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks you want to alter the zoom state of the [`WebView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) based on an event, so you should update the [`zoom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#zoomProperty) property held by the `WebView` itself. Starting form this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824164/230513), I added the following `EventFilter` based on your example. It appears to work as expected.

```
webView.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, (KeyEvent e) -> {
    if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ADD || e.getCode() == KeyCode.EQUALS
            || e.getCode() == KeyCode.PLUS) {
        System.out.println("+");
        webView.setZoom(webView.getZoom() * 1.1);
    }
    else if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.SUBTRACT || e.getCode() == KeyCode.MINUS ){
        System.out.println("-");
        webView.setZoom(webView.getZoom() / 1.1);
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: trashgod how to change this to set zoom level so when we zoom first picture the second image should load with same level.

Comment: Maybe save the current zoom, perhaps among your current `Preferences` for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616583/230513), so you can restore it when needed.