# Problem centering pane and border on JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having trouble with the following code. My `Box` and `border` does not want to center. It keeps reverting to the top left corner. I need it to snap to the center when running the program. I'm new to programming so the issue might be something simple. I have also tried shifting by the `width` of the border using the `setTranslateX` and `setTranslateY` methods. This causes the `boxPane` to be centered in the `StackPane`

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Movable Box with Border and Grid");

        int gridSize = 28;
        double boxSize = 500.0; // size of the box
        double borderWidth = 2.0; // width of the border
        double cellSize = boxSize / gridSize;  // size of each cell

        Pane grid = new Pane();
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
                Rectangle cell = new Rectangle(cellSize, cellSize);
                cell.setFill(Color.WHITE);
                cell.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                cell.setStrokeWidth(0.5);
                cell.setX(j * cellSize + borderWidth / 2);
                cell.setY(i * cellSize + borderWidth / 2);
                grid.getChildren().add(cell);
            }
        }

        // Create a border around the grid
        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(boxSize + borderWidth, boxSize + borderWidth);
        border.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        border.setStrokeWidth(borderWidth);
        border.setX(borderWidth / 2);
        border.setY(borderWidth / 2);

        Pane boxPane = new Pane();
        boxPane.getChildren().addAll(border, grid);

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(boxPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 700);

        scene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            double zoomFactor = 1.05;
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
            if (deltaY < 0){
                zoomFactor = 2 - zoomFactor;
            }
            boxPane.setScaleX(boxPane.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
            boxPane.setScaleY(boxPane.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
            event.consume();
        });

        boxPane.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double newX = event.getSceneX() - boxSize / 2;
            double newY = event.getSceneY() - boxSize / 2;
            boxPane.setTranslateX(newX);
            boxPane.setTranslateY(newY);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I tried changing the `box` and `scene` size

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  It is a "Movable Box".  How can it be centered when it is moved?

Answer (score 1):

While `StackPane` is excellent for centering, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824164/230513), it's superfluous in this case:

```
Pane boxPane = new Pane();
boxPane.getChildren().addAll(border, grid);
//StackPane root = new StackPane();
//root.getChildren().add(boxPane);
Scene scene = new Scene(boxPane, 700, 700);
```

To center the `boxPane` at startup, adjust its position *after* `show()`, using the available geometry:

```
primaryStage.show();
boxPane.setTranslateX((boxPane.getWidth() - boxSize) / 2);
boxPane.setTranslateY((boxPane.getHeight() - boxSize) / 2);
```

The existing drag handler centers the `boxPane` under the mouse. To change this behavior, record the location of the mouse pressed event and use it to adjust the target location in your drag handler; some examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76717235/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bjavafx%5D%20%5Bjavafx%5D%20setOnMousePressed%20setOnMouseDragged&searchOn=3):

```
boxPane.setOnMousePressed((event) -> {
    // record mouse location for later reference
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @trashgod mentioned.

Below are my additional points for you to consider *if needed ;)* :

- Why don't you consider to use a GridPane rather than positioning each cell manually to form like a grid.
- Do you really need `Rectangle` as your cell. If you are going to show something in the cell, I believe you will include a `Pane` and set the `Rectangle` for background and some node as content. So why don't you consider to use directly a `Pane` as cell with some border styling, so that you can avoid an extra node(Rectangle) per cell. This is just a thought :)
- I believe you are trying something with borders to make it look like a perfect grid with equal border widths for all cells. You can try the below approach:

  The idea is, we don't set all borders to a cell. Instead we only set right and bottom border for every cell. and for the container (GridPane) we set only the top and left borders. Which when finally rendered will make a perfect grid (as below).

[image]

After combining all the above points (including @trashgod solution) below is quick demo for your reference:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MovableBoxDemo extends Application {

    private double lx, ly, x, y;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX Movable Box with Border and Grid");

        int gridSize = 28;
        double boxSize = 500.0; // size of the box
        double cellSize = boxSize / gridSize;  // size of each cell

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 1 0 0 1;-fx-border-color:black;");
        for (int i = 0; i < gridSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
                Pane cell = new Pane();
                cell.setPrefSize(cellSize, cellSize);
                cell.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 1 1 0;-fx-border-color:black;-fx-background-color:white;");
                grid.add(cell, i, j);
            }
        }

        Pane boxPane = new Pane(grid);
        Scene scene = new Scene(boxPane, 700, 700);
        scene.setOnScroll((ScrollEvent event) -> {
            double zoomFactor = 1.05;
            double deltaY = event.getDeltaY();
            if (deltaY < 0) {
                zoomFactor = 2 - zoomFactor;
            }
            boxPane.setScaleX(boxPane.getScaleX() * zoomFactor);
            boxPane.setScaleY(boxPane.getScaleY() * zoomFactor);
            event.consume();
        });
        boxPane.setOnMousePressed(event -> {
            x = event.getSceneX();
            y = event.getSceneY();
            lx = boxPane.getLayoutX();
            ly = boxPane.getLayoutY();
        });
        boxPane.setOnMouseDragged(event -> {
            double diffX = event.getSceneX() - x;
            double diffY = event.getSceneY() - y;
            boxPane.setLayoutX(lx + diffX);
            boxPane.setLayoutY(ly + diffY);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        boxPane.setLayoutX((boxPane.getWidth() - boxSize) / 2);
        boxPane.setLayoutY((boxPane.getHeight() - boxSize) / 2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```