# Why am i getting an error when I run javafx webview?

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine, javafx-webview

[my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5t8B.png)

So I imported everything I need for javafx webview. I also added the vm arguments in eclipse, which are these:
--module-path /Users/easwar/Downloads/javafx-sdk-21.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.media

--add-modules javafx.web

but whenever I run it, i keep getting this error message:

```
thread set port failed due to (os/kern) invalid argument
```

I am trying to load the url: http://www.google.com but it doesn't work.

complete error message:

[image: msg]

I've done a bit of looking around and it seems like there may be a incompatibility between my javafx and java versions. Right now I am using javafx version 21 and java version 19.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the URL you're using as well as a [mre] that illustrates the problem you describe.

Comment: Also post the complete error message, formatted as code

Comment: What do you mean by adding a url?

Comment: @MessiSkillz: `WebView` displays content identified by its [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax), which may include an optional _port_ number. Your error fragment mentions the word _port_.

Comment: @trashgod i was trying to use webview to display the url: http://google.com
I don't know if this has any port number associated with it

Comment: To narrow it down, you might try this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33824164/230513) that includes a working URL

Comment: @trashgod something interesting happened, i tried using http://example.com as my url and it worked. Is there any reason that http://google.com isn't working?
also http://youtube.com isn't working either.

Comment: At a guess, your link is missing a _scheme_; [edit] your question to show the URL you _actually_ use.

Comment: ok i added the url, i was using http://google.com

Comment: Google (and Youtube) uses `https`, not `http`.  If you use `http` to access `http://www.google.com`, google will (automatically) redirect you to `https://www.google.com`.  https runs on port 443 and http on port 80.  Plus, https access requires SSL to be working.  But that should all be OK (I don't know what is causing your weird port error).  Upgrade to the latest stable Java version (may not fix your issue).   Also, you only need a single `--add-modules` argument: `--add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web`.

Comment: In your error message, it states that you are using JDK 17 for an Intel Mac (not Java 19 as you state in your question).  Use JDK 21 and ensure that you are using the correct architecture version for the system you are using for both the JDK and JavaFX (if it is an Intel mac, that would be the x64 mac versions, and for an M processor mac that would be aarch64 mac versions).

Comment: I am using an apple M1 processor

Comment: @jewelsea's point is well taken; you may want to consider re-installing.