# JxBrowser freezes whole application

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

i embedded jxBrowser to my java (Swing) Application. When an error occurs this freezes my entire application ;( 
Is there a way to part the JxBrowser error so that I can continue to work normally in my application?

Best regards,
Pirol

Comment: A related example using [tag:javafx] is seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513).

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say why some error causes entire application freezing. An example or steps to reproduce would help in resolving this issue. You could try checking the dump of Java threads when freezing happens. Maybe an error causes threads deadlock?

Comment: If an error happens again, I will create a threaddump and browse these!