# Java (Netbeans) : Connecting Google Search To JTextField

Tags: java, swing, google-chrome, google-app-engine, netbeans

Is there any way to connect google search to **jtextfield**, i want to create a software that can search directly through a **jtextfield** and the results would show up on a different **JPanel**. i found a code that will make it search on google directly but you need an existing browser to do it, i just want the results to appear on a different panel, for example when you search something on the **textfield** the results will popup on another panel.

this is the code that i found but it needs an existing browser i want the software to be standalone thats all thank you:

```
try {
         String search = "#q="+jTextField.getText().toString().trim();
         search = search.replaceAll(" ","+");
         String url = "http:////www.google.com//"+search;
         java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create(url));
       }
       catch (java.io.IOException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
       }
```

Comment: In Java 8, try `WebView`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31576647/230513).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Best Java/Swing browser component?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/145863/230513)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not interested in writing your own browser you could use [this](https://www.teamdev.com/jxbrowser).