# Implementing automatic reminders in java

Tags: java, swing, timer-jobs

I have to remind the user about schedules which he did previously in java. I know i can do with timers but how do i do tat ? actually i need to remind about many schedules so do i have to create timers for each schedules or can i handle it with just one timer ?

------EDIT--------------
I am designing point of sale software and i need to have phone booking and delivery system with this. So when a delivery or phone booking is done it should remind the staff just 10  before the scheduled time.. so i may have as many deliveries and phone bookings so does this helps ?

Comment: For example, here's a [simple timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373625) that's relative to GUI a event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell just from your description, but you may well want to look at the [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/) library.