# How to make the main GUI thread 'wait' until a separate pop-up window is disappeared

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, awt

I have an object which is invoked from the main GUI thread and shows a separate JFrame for a number of seconds and then disappear (with the use of a timer). Now I want to make the main GUI thread to wait until the pop-up JFrame window disappears. For example, on the main GUI code:

```
// initiate the object and show the pop-up JFrame
DisappearingJFrame djf = new DisappearingJFrame ();
djf.show ();

// now the main GUI thread should wait
// and after the pop-up JFrame disappears, the rest of the code is then executed
...
...
```

Any suggestion would be welcome. Thanks.

Comment: If the popup `JFrame` is not complex, why not just use a Modal `JDialog` on top of your main window?

Comment: You mean making a customised JDialog with a timer that would disappear after a number of seconds?

Comment: yes. Though I have no idea what asgs meant about "is not complex". Do this even if the JFrame is complex.

Comment: See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373493/java-swing-timer-how-to-hide-box-and-reappear-after-1-hour/4373625#4373625).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a separate JFrame for this is what modal dialogs were built for. Use either a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog.

Answer (score 5):

> I have an object which is invoked from the main GUI thread and shows a separate JFrame

If you want to show more than one [TopLayoutContainer(s)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) maybe it is better to look for [JDialog](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) because with that you can play with [ModalityType](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.html#setModalityType%28java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType%29) & [toFront()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#toFront%28%29).

Isn't method `show()` deprecated and replaced with method [JDialog.setVisible(boolean)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setVisible%28boolean%29)?