# Java swing timers and pause program?

Tags: java, swing, timer

I'm trying to simulate waiting in a java swing application, so it's basically like this: the user presses a button (Already added an actionlistener) then the program basically makes a 5 seconds pause while working in the background, then when the 5 seconds have elapsed a window shows up. ( I know how to make the window). Basically I'm asking how do you work with swing timers? Is there a command like pause() that can be invoked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might get some ideas from [`TimerFrame`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373625/230513). See also [*Using Timers in Swing Applications*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/).

Answer (score 2):

you might want to check this example from the docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TumbleItemProject/src/components/TumbleItem.java

basically you can define an initial delay before it fires - in your case 5 seconds - and simply start it.