# Show a panel after x seconds after button click

Tags: java, swing, timer

i'm extremely new to java. i have a simple program here and what i want is to show a certain JPanel, after x seconds delay, when a button is clicked.

what i want in particular is something like a "start game" button, and upon clicking it, a panel that contains a "loading..." animation would be shown temporarily in the JFrame in x seconds, then another panel would show up after this.

i'm aware Timers would be the answer to this. but i've done all the thinking and research that needs to be done first. my last resort is to ask it here. i need at least a sample code upon which i can figure out the rest by myself

i'm badly in need. i have acquired poor java knowledge in a short period of time and my instructor expects a spectacular output from me. thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html

Comment: Study about java threads they will help you in this

Comment: What have you tried? Please show some effort (code). Btw. read about `java threads`, it is basically the answer to your question.

Comment: Why would you want to add an artificial delay and make the user wait longer if nothing is actually loading?

Comment: `i'm aware Timers would be the answer to this` - That is correct.  `i need at least a sample code upon which i can figure out the rest by myself` - if you have done all the searching that you suggest then you should have found plenty of sameple code because the forum is full of examples that use a Timer. So post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates what you have tried, then we can offer some help.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4373625/230513).

Answer (score 0):

Simply write `Thread.sleep(x*1000);` after clicking the button.

It will make the application wait for **x** seconds. After completing **x** seconds application will proceed further.