# How to make a 3 minutes countdown timer

Tags: java, swing, timer, actionlistener, minute

I want to use the method `javax.swing.Timer` to create a timer that will start at 3:00, then go down to 0:00. I have no idea how to use this method and how to proceed. From now on, I have this code, but I have no idea if it is good. One thing sure is that it doesn't work.

```
private javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        int minute = 3;
        int seconde = 60;
        do {
            lblTimer.setText(Integer.toString(seconde));
            seconde--;
        } while (seconde != 0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373625/230513), a `TimerButton` responds after the delay passed to the constructor, e.g.

```
new TimerButton("Back in three minutes", 3 * 60 * 1000));
```

Your `StopListener` would take the desired action when the `Timer` expires, e.g.

```
private class StopListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
        // further actions here
    }
}
```

See [*How to Use Swing Timers*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for additional details.